# When will ASP.NET kill a new thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, timeout

I've tried some googling on this subject but i would like to have som more info.

I'm trying to start a new thread inside an ASP.NET app that will take care of some work that takes long time. If I put this in my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="5" />
```

A regular request will timeout after 5 secounds. Remember this is for testing. When I start a new thread from the code:

```
    var testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CustomClass.DoStuffThatTakesLongTime));
    testThread.Start();
```

This thread will run for longer than 5 secounds, that's what I want. BUT. For how long will it run? Let's say this thread takes 5h (just as an example). When will the thread be killed? Will it run until the app pool is recycled? Or is there anything else that kills this thread?

Comment: Try it out, see what happens. (Let the new thread write the time to a textfile or so) 
EDIT: check if there is a difference between using Thread and Task.

Comment: That's want I did but I would like some more understading. The thread seams to run, but I would like to know more about what could go wrong and what to look up for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET has no knowledge of the thread that you have created - it will run until the AppPool is recycled or it completes.

Since ASP.Net has no knowledge of this thread however, it *could* be aborted quite abruptly at any point if the server thinks that it should recycle the AppPool, this would not be a good thing! [Phil Haack wrote a blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) on how to subscribe to the 'AppDomainIsGoingDown' event.

In regards to what can cause this, I'd recommend reading this [blog post by Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx), but in a nutshell they are:

> - It has been scheduled to do so
> - Machine.Config, Web.Config or Global.asax are modified
> - The bin directory or its contents is modified
> - The number of re-compilations (aspx, ascx or asax) exceeds the limit specified by the  setting in machine.config or web.config  (by default this is set to 15)
> - The physical path of the virtual directory is modified
> - The CAS policy is modified
> - The web service is restarted
> - (2.0 only) Application Sub-Directories are deleted

Comment: So that means that this "exemple"-thread will run for 5h. Will GC take care of stuff when the thread complets or do I need to release resources in any way?

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson The thread will run until it completes or the AppPool is shut down. All the resources acquired during the lifetime of the Thread are managed, all necessary GC will still be performed.

Comment: So. About the fact that the thread could be aborted by the server. Would this happen is the thread is actually working with something? Or just if its idle? Is there any way to "protect" against this?

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson Yes, irrespective of whether the thread is working on something or idle it could be aborted. In order to inform ASP.Net that your thread is working you'll need to implement IRegisteredObject and call the HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject and UnregisterObject methods during the relevent lifetime of your work. I highly recommend reading Phil Haack's blog post - it describes exactly what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson I've updated my answer, hopefully this provides the information you were looking for. If not just let me know and I'll see if I can help.